# freeradius authenticate over ldap log files

Tags: linux, ldap, radius, freeradius2

when config free-radius to authenticate over ldap where are the log files that store usernames and other connected client info?

excuse me for my bad English.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you are looking for, but freeradius logfiles will be in the location defined in the radiusd.conf file in the `logdir` variable/directive.  Likely to be `/var/log/freeradius` for most distros.